# Outtputing several tables on one page in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny interface that takes in a datafile name, and then runs an .R script that generates 4 tables(matrices), and outputs them all at once in Shiny. For example:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Calculate CDK fingerprints"),
    sidebarPanel(
        textInput("text_input_fingerprints", "Enter smiles file name:"),
        actionButton("runButton", "Run")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("cdk")
    )
   )
  )
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

output$cdk <- renderTable({

    input$runButton

    if (input$runButton == 0) {return()}        
    else{
         source('calculate_cdk_fingerprints.R', local = TRUE)
         print(table1)
         print(table2)
         print(table3)
         print(table4)
        }
     })
})
```

Unfortunately, Shiny only prints the last table, table 4. And I can't really split the .R script, as it also outputs some files to a local folder. And yes, I really need to use the actionButton().

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a separate renderTable() call for each table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate table output for each.  Alternatively, you could use `verbatimTextSummary` with `rbind`

```
mainPanel(
    tableOutput("cdk1"),
    tableOutput("cdk2"),
    tableOutput("cdk3")
)
```

---

#### ui.r

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Calculate CDK fingerprints"),
    sidebarPanel(
        textInput("text_input_fingerprints", "Enter smiles file name:"),
        actionButton("runButton", "Run")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("cdk1"),
        tableOutput("cdk2"),
        tableOutput("cdk3")
    )
   )
  )
```

## server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

#----
## eg: 
# source('calculate_cdk_fingerprints.R', local = TRUE)
#-----
## Example: 
table1 <- matrix(1:20, nrow=4)
table2 <- matrix(101:120, nrow=4)
table3 <- matrix(201:220, nrow=4)


output$cdk1 <- renderTable({

    input$runButton

    if (input$runButton == 0) {return()}        
    else{
         table1
        }
     })

output$cdk2 <- renderTable({

    input$runButton

    if (input$runButton == 0) {return()}        
    else{
         table2
        }
     })

output$cdk3 <- renderTable({

    input$runButton

    if (input$runButton == 0) {return()}        
    else{
         table3
        }
     })
})
```

Comment: This is almost correct; but I think @ssantic wanted the data (re-)calculated when the action button was pressed. There needs to be a reactive expression, say `calc`, that runs `source('calculate_cdk_fingerprints.R', local = TRUE)` and returns `list(table1, table2, table3, table4)`, and the `renderTable` calls can do `calc()[[1]]` and so on. (Oh and the reactive expression should immediately return `NULL` if `input$runButton == 0`, and the `renderTable` calls should check for `NULL` when they access `calc()`.)

Comment: Joe, thanks for chiming in!  Please feel free to edit my answer as appropriate

Comment: @JoeCheng Actually, I don't need the data to be recalculated - the .R script calculates the data for the 4 tables, and outputs the results into .csv files, plus I need to show the tables in Shiny visually. EDIT: The above solution is OK, but the problem is I can't source() the .R script before the 4 renderTable functions - it needs to be run after inputs are given and the actionButton is pressed...

Comment: And if I run the source() script in, for example, output$cdk1, and then try just printing table2 in output$cdk2, R tells me can't find object 'table2'.

Comment: @ssantic if that's the case then have an `input` create a list of the tables (based on whatever user selection), then each rendering should element should output one table from the list

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Could you please give me a code example how to do this? Thank you.